# Python extract tags from string by string array

Tags: python

I am new to python and looking help to extract tags from string by string array. Let's say I have string array of `['python', 'c#', 'java', 'f#' ]`

And input string of `"I love Java and python"`.

The output should be array `['java', 'python']`

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is best accomplished using sets. Are you familiar with sets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Non-splittable by blankspace

#### Regex solution

```
import re

stringarray = ['python', 'c#', 'core java', 'f#' ]
string = "I love Core Java and python"

pattern = '|'.join(stringarray)    
output = re.findall(pattern, string.lower())
# ['core java', 'python']
```

#### Non-regex solution

```
stringarray = ['python', 'c#', 'core java', 'f#' ]
string = "I love Core Java and python"
output = [i for i in stringarray if i in string.lower()]
# ['core java', 'python']
```

---

### Splittable by blankspace, or other char (quicker!)

#### Using set and intersection

```
stringarray = ['python', 'c#', 'java', 'f#' ]
string = "I love Java and python"

output = list(set(string.lower().split()).intersection(stringarray))
# ['java', 'python']
```

**Short explanation:** By doing `string.lower().split()` we split the words as lower-case in your inputstring by the default (blankspace). By converting it to a set we can access the set function intersection. Intersection will in turn find the occurences that are in both sets. Finally we wrap this around a list to get desired output. As commented by Joe Iddon this will not return repeated tags.

#### Counts

Are you interested in counts? Consider using collections counter and a dict comprehension:

```
from collections import Counter

count = {k:v for k,v in Counter(string.lower().split()).items() if k in stringarray}
print(count)
#{'java': 1, 'python': 1}
```

Comment: this does not return repeated tags though (if that is required), good if that is not required +1

Comment: Thanks @Anton i found another scenario where array is like ['python', 'c#', 'core java', 'f#' ]. Here we have a space in "core java" and string is "I love Core Java and python". in this case spiting string by space does not return desired result. Is the any way to resolve this?

Comment: @user2172306 In that case we must go for a regex solution I'd say. Are you familiar with regex?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following list comprehension, which turns your string into lowercase, then iterates through each word (after using `split`), and returns which ones are in your array:

```
arr = ['python', 'c#', 'java', 'f#' ]
s = "I love Java and python"

outp = [i for i in s.lower().split() if i in arr]

>>> outp
['java', 'python']
```

Or you could use regular expressions:

```
import re

arr = ['python', 'c#', 'java', 'f#' ]
s = "I love Java and python"

outp = re.findall('|'.join(arr),s.lower())

>>> outp 
['java', 'python']
```

Answer (score 2):

Turn your tags list into a set, so lookup is average case `O(1)` lookup, and then use a list-comprehension to perform an `O(1)` tag search.

```
def extract(string, tags):
     tags = set(tags)
     return [w for w in string.lower().split() if w in tags]
```

and a test:

```
>>> extract('I love Java and python', ['python', 'c#', 'java', 'f#' ])
['java', 'python']
```